# passing command-range to a function

Tags: vim

I'm trying to define a command that can take a range and pass it to a function. This is what I thought I should have:

```
function! PrintGivenRange() range
    echo "firstline ".a:firstline." lastline ".a:lastline
    " Do some more things
endfunction

command! -range PassRange call PrintGivenRange()
```

However, it doesn't work that way, it seems to only pass the first line.

e.g.

```
:1,5PassRange "outputs firstline 1 lastline 1
:1,5call PrintGivenRange() "outputs firstline 1 lastline 5
" if you select lines in visual mode, same thing for both
```

I've read `:help command-range` already but still haven't been able to figure this out. Am I supposed to pass the range in the prefix to the `call`? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to explicitly pass the range, try with:

```
command! -range PassRange <line1>,<line2>call PrintGivenRange()
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! (I will accept your answer as soon as I can)  It's weird that the syntax is different inside and outside a function (that might be why I missed the <line1>,<line2> syntax).

Comment: Looking at the help text again, I realized that I just didn't understand what "command line range" meant.

Answer (score 4):

If you want use the range of currently selected line in visual mode, you can use the below:

```
command! -range PassRange '<,'> call PrintGivenRange()
```

- `'<`: the first line of the current selected Visual area in the current buffer.
- `'>`: the last line of the current selected Visual area in the current buffer.